# Adding a 8080 to each URl using URl rewriting?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a domain like www.mytest.com. Now for each subpage of that page and the domain itself I want to add :8080. Like this:

*www.mytest.com/correct.php --> www.mytest.com:8080/correct.php*

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy pass reverse assuming that you activate (listen on) port 8080 in your httpd.conf file or VirtualHost file assuming you're using Apache HTTPD and have root access.  If not, believe you can put this into .htaccess:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset Off
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://www.mytest.com:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mytest.com:8080
</VirtualHost>
```